# How to create nested forms using rails 3 and datamapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, datamapper, cocoon-gem

**my models in Datamapper are:**

**Project:**

```
require "dm-accepts_nested_attributes"

class Project

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :project_title, String

  has n, :tasks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
```

end

**Task:**

```
class Task

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  property :task_name, String

  belongs_to :project

end
```

Now i wanted to create view for the Project with links for adding tasks.
I tried it with [nested_form](https://github.com/madebydna/nested_form) gem 
and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem but no use.

Comment: Hey i solved this by using the solution found in The Pragmatic Bookshelf Rails Recipes book. Though the book covers mainly Rails2.3 but i was able to do it with Rails 3.

Comment: Afaik the cocoon gem does not rely on activerecord (but truth be told: never tried to use datamapper). Could you show some code?

Comment: never mind. Our application moved to active-record and it's working great with cocoon gem.